# vuejs foreach loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В общем есть у меня контроллер на стороне сервера который через ajax выдает все категории с подкатегориями. Неизвестно какой максимальный уровень вложенности будет. Как во vuejs провернуть такой вывод - ума не приложу. Подскажите направление, или готовые примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну похоже компонент нужно будет вызывать рекурсивно, быстрое гугленье выдало вот что https://alligator.io/vuejs/recursive-components/, а вот прям из документации пример построения похожего дерева - https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/examples/tree-view.html